# Worksheet calculation to ignore blanks - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Somebody help! This driving me crazy! I need to find the lowest three calculated values only from cells that have a value in vaNums. I need vaNums / vaDenoms. From that calculation find the three lowest, but ONLY from cells that have a value in vaNums. If a zero is in vaNums then that can be included as one of the three lowest. If vaNums is blank then it should NOT be included as one of the three.  Example: 0 / 20 = 0 (that can be included as one of the three lowest) blank / 20 = 0 (that can NOT be included as one of the three lowest) Please help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim vaNums As Variant, vaDenoms As Variant, aDivs() As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim lSmall As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rStart As Range
Dim iCount As Integer
Const lCols As Long = 10
Const lMarkcnt As Long = 3
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set rRow = target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, lCols)
Set rStart = Me.Cells(1, 5)
iCount = wf.CountA(rRow, ">0")
If Not Intersect(target.Cells(1), Me.Range("D3", Me.Range("D3").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then
If iCount > 4 Then
    Set rRow = target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, iCount)
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    vaNums = rRow.Value
    vaDenoms = rStart.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, lCols).Value
    ReDim aDivs(LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2))
    For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
        aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i) + (i / 10000)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 3
        lSmall = wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False)
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Interior.Color = 6299648
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    Next i
Else
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If
Else
rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Posting a sample workbook you are using with this code would help - it is complex code on a standalone basis

Answer (score 0):

> Worksheet calculation to ignore blanks - VBA
>
> I need to find the lowest three calculated values only from cells that have a value in vaNums.
>
> If vaNums is blank then it should NOT be included as one of the three.

Rather simple isn't it if I have understood you correctly? Use `.SpecialCells`. It returns a Range object that represents all the cells that match the specified type and value.

Syntax

*expression.SpecialCells(Type, Value)*

Read up more about it in the Inbuilt Help.

Let's say your range is `A1:D10`

Simply use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Change worksheet name and range as applicable
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D10")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
        ReDim MyAr(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
        
        i = 1
        
        For Each aCell In rng
            MyAr(i) = aCell.Value
            i = i + 1
        Next
        
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            Debug.Print MyAr(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the portion of code that I needed. Hopefully, it makes sense apart from the broader context:

```
For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
    If IsEmpty(vaNums(1, i)) Then
        aDivs(i) = Empty
    Else
        aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i) + (i / 10000)
    End If
Next I
```

The first code I posted was given by another. I just needed to tweak it. Thanks to everyone who helped!